# How to support a datetime-local type for all kind of OS and Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project i have a option for date select. For that i am using a type datetime-local.

But it is not working in mozila firefox browser and also in a mac os system. 
How can i solve this issue?

I want to support my datetime-local type to all kind browsers and OS.

Anyone Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now from your comment. The answer is you cannot use this in a lot of browsers and a javascript plugin is still the best option.

See this support table.
https://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local

Comment: <input type="datetime-local"> This is not supporting in mozila firefoox browser and mac os system.

Comment: How can i make the above type supporting in all the browsers and OS

Comment: see update answer it is not possible to support all browsers, better to use a javascript plugin.

Comment: I used <script>
    $(function(){
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.datetime-local) {
            $('input[type=datetime-local]').datepicker({
                        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                    }
            );
        }
    });
</script> but it is not working

Comment: modernizer is just a tool for feature detection it will not make the missing feature work, it will only detect if the feature is avaiable or not.

if (Modernizr.awesomeNewFeature) {
    showOffAwesomeNewFeature();
  } else {
    getTheOldLameExperience();
  }

Comment: as mentioned before you need to use a javascript plugin. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ is a good one with many options, but it is up to you to choose what is best for your project.